# Visual Basic Vs Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: dreamweaver

HI ,

I was wondering if you could help me.

I know its not totally programing related but its sort of related

I am a junior web developer and I work mainly with PHP , MySQL , Javascript and HTML I dont really touch design.

I run a mac so if i go with VS I have will to run it using Bootcamp.

But what is the best VS or Dreamweaver ?

Also could you tell me what each is mainly focused for ?

Comment: This sort of question has a tendency to get closed.  Be more specific "best" for what set of requirements in more detail

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio is mostly .NET orientated, so Dreamweaver would be a better bet for PHP.

I think you should check out Aptana which I prefer to Dreamweaver, which has the advantage of being available for bothe platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing apples and pears here :) The products are not comparable, because they are for entirely different tasks. Dreamweaver focuses on web design (HTML, CSS, Javascript, etc...) while visual studio focuses on programming (desktop applications for windows, mainly).

Dreamveaver and VS meet when you develop for the web on asp.net on visual studio: you can design the interface in dreamweaver and then integrate it in your asp.net project... but that's all...

Comment: I see , I think I have got the wrong impression of VS. 

Thanks this is why I love Stack :)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic (6, .net, etc) is a language and development environment all wrapped in one. It allows you to design forms(windows) and code them all within that one environment.

dreamweaver(also known as devil spawn) is a language editor that is not based on any one language. It's a notepad on steroids.

Answer (score 0):

For what you're doing, I don't see a need for neither Visual Studio nor Dreamweaver. Why don't you check out [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)?

Visual Basic 6 = For development of Windows applications or COM-libraries
Current version of Visual Studio = For development of anything .net including web apps with html, javascript etcetera.
Dreamweaver = More a program for users than for developers, though I haven't used it in ages

Comment: So for a junior developer who wants to be a good developer in the future you could say I am best staying clear of Dreamweaver

Comment: I wouldn't use it for production, though if the code just doesn't matter, as in a prototype, you could use it to drag a site together. If I where doing web with PHP on a Mac I'd investigate Coda, because it seems really nice.

Comment: Old thread here I know, but just wanted to comment on how Dreamweaver can function as a perfectly-good code (text) editor, with syntax coloring, code (tag/attribute) completion, and FTP support built into it. Some designers love it for its drag and drop creation ability, but that's not all it does. I myself have used it for days if not weeks on end purely in "code" view, almost never switching to design view. I disagree that it is not a useful application, it just depends on what you want to use it for.

Answer (score 0):

I code in ColdFusion and PHP. Based on the your statement that you don't do much design, I would recommend Eclipse and the myriad of plugins you can use to make it into a fully customizable IDE.

Because of my job duties, I have to do some design and code.  Dreamweaver is nice with their design view if you are working with HTML.  Eclipse beats it hands down when it comes doing coding.  Aptana is a good plugin for Eclipse (or as a standalone based on Eclipse) if you want more tools for HTML and popular Javascript library support.

Also, Eclipse is free.

Hope this helps.